# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting some error

> Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.

And Show Something like that as well
Required by:
project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0 > androidx.core:core:1.7.0
> androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0

How can I solve that issue. Please Some one Help Me

Here is My **Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bloodbuddy"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'


implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'



testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: Post full error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found the answer? Because you didn't show your project root `build.gradle` and maybe the build.gradle in your project root directory didn't have the `mavenCentral()` repository.

Just go to your build.gradle repository and add the `mavenCentral()`.

Project root directory `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // <= add this
    }
    dependencies {
        // make sure to have this classpath
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

........

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // <= add this
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```